# Way to use system properties with annotation in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, annotations

Is there any chance to use annotatios with system properties in Selenium?

```
@Test
public void
testSigninMobile()
{
   if(System.getProperty("browser").equals("iphone")){
        login();
   }else{
        driver.quit();
   } 

}
```

I would like to have annotations like that:

```
@Test if broswer is iphone, firefox but not if it is IE or Edge etc.
public void
testSigninMobile()
{...
```

I mean the situation where you have for instance 50 tests but your app is not full ready for every browser. I think that it is silly to write to those 50 test such a browser checking logic?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a priority value to the more important tests?  The syntax is, `@Test(priority=X)`.  The tells your frame work to run, consider running or not run at all, based on the value assigned to priority.

Comment: Can you give that priority in mvn script like mvn test -Dpriority=10?

Comment: I think the priority starts at '0' and goes up from there to 5.  Try that.

Comment: But I need to give that as a parameter in mvn script. For instance I would like to drive only tests with priority 1, not 2 or 3 and somehow I need to tell that before tests will run.

Comment: for JUnit http://www.codeaffine.com/2013/11/18/a-junit-rule-to-conditionally-ignore-tests/
for TestNG http://blog.xebia.com/conditionally-running-tests-in-testng/

Answer (score 0):

You can write logics inside the @Test method using Capabilities - getBrowserName().

```
@Test
public void testSigninMobile()
{
   Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
   String browserName = cap.getBrowserName().toLowerCase();
   System.out.println(browserName);
   if("blabla".equalsIgnoreCase(browserName))
   {
      // Your code
   }
   else
   {
      throw new SkipException("Skipping this excecution");
   }
}
```